# Issue on Mapping Array of Arrays to one Single Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can map an array of arrays into a new array?

I tried this already but look like I am missing some things here

```js
var array1 = [
               [1, 4, 6, 78],
               [5, 3, 9, 21],
               [11, 77, 9, 20],
               ];
var arr2 = []
const map1 = array1.map(arr2.push(x => x ));

console.log(arr2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to achieve what you require is to use [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
var array1 = [
  [1, 4, 6, 78],
  [5, 3, 9, 21],
  [11, 77, 9, 20],
];
var arr2 = array1.flat();

console.log(arr2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However you should note that this method is unsupported in both IE and Edge, although a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Polyfill) is available.

Answer (score 3):

First note that the code you have wrote `array1.map(arr2.push(x => x));` don't have any sense and won't work, because [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should take a function as argument and you are passing the result of a `push()`, i.e, the length of `arr2` after you push the identity function on it (`x => x`). So, if you are able to, use [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) instead:

```js
var array1 = [
    [1, 4, 6, 78],
    [5, 3, 9, 21],
    [11, 77, 9, 20],
];

let array2 = array1.flat();
console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or alternatively [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
var array1 = [
    [1, 4, 6, 78],
    [5, 3, 9, 21],
    [11, 77, 9, 20],
];

let array2 = array1.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), []);
console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

A close idea to what I believe you wanted to do is shown on next example:

```js
var array1 = [
    [1, 4, 6, 78],
    [5, 3, 9, 21],
    [11, 77, 9, 20],
];

let array2 = [];
array1.forEach(innerArr => innerArr.forEach(v => array2.push(v)));
console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.concat.apply` to reduce the number of inner arrays by one.

```js
var array1 = [
               [1, 4, 6, 78],
               [5, 3, 9, 21],
               [11, 77, 9, 20],
               ];
var arr2 = [].concat.apply([], array1);

console.log(arr2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```